# CSS transition between left -> right and top -> bottom positions

Tags: css, css-transitions

Is it possible to use CSS transitions to animate something between a position set as `left: 0px` to `right: 0px` so it goes all the way across the screen? I need to accomplish the same thing with top to bottom. Am I stuck calculating the screen width / object-size?

```css
#nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.moveto {
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

and then I use jQuery's `.addClass`

Comment: So, *what* have you tried? What HTML are you working with? CSS, any JavaScript? Do you have [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you've got so far..?

Comment: @David Thomas see edits.

Comment: Thanks! ...could we see the (relevant) HTML and jQuery as well?

Comment: In more modern browsers, you can also use [`calc()`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) to determine positions, which helps by allowing you to do things like `.moveto { left: calc(100% - 50px); }`.

Answer (score 49):

You can animate the position (top, bottom, left, right) and then subtract the element's width or height through a CSS transformation.

Consider:

```js
$('.animate').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("move");
})
```

```css
     .animate {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: #c00;
        transition: all 1s ease;
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
        font: 13px/100px sans-serif;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
      }

                               /* ↓ just to position things  */
      .animate.left   { left: 0;   top: 50%;  margin-top: -100px;}
      .animate.right  { right: 0;  top: 50%;  }
      .animate.top    { top: 0;    left: 50%; }
      .animate.bottom { bottom: 0; left: 50%; margin-left: -100px;}


      .animate.left.move {
        left: 100%; 
        transform: translate(-100%, 0);
      }

      .animate.right.move {
        right: 100%; 
        transform: translate(100%, 0);
      }

      .animate.top.move {
        top: 100%; 
        transform: translate(0, -100%);
      }

      .animate.bottom.move {
        bottom: 100%; 
        transform: translate(0, 100%);
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click to animate
<div class="animate left">left</div>
<div class="animate top">top</div>
<div class="animate bottom">bottom</div>
<div class="animate right">right</div>
```

And then animate depending on the position...

Comment: You may want to add an elastic easing transition http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23462515/elastic-easing-in-css3-best-approach

Answer (score 15):

For elements with **dynamic width** it's possible to use `transform: translateX(-100%);` to counter the horizontal percentage value. This leads to two possible solutions:

### 1. Option: moving the element in the entire viewport:

Transition from:

```
transform: translateX(0);
```

to

```
transform: translateX(calc(100vw - 100%));
```

```css
#viewportPendulum {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  animation: 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate swingViewport;
  /* just for styling purposes */
  background: #c70039;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

@keyframes swingViewport {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(calc(100vw - 100%));
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="viewportPendulum">Viewport</div>
```

### 2. Option: moving the element in the parent container:

Transition from:

```
transform: translateX(0);
left: 0;
```

to

```
left: 100%;
transform: translateX(-100%);
```

```css
#parentPendulum {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate swingParent;
  /* just for styling purposes */
  background: #c70039;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

@keyframes swingParent {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
    left: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 2rem 0;
  margin: 2rem 15%;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="parentPendulum">Parent</div>
</div>
```

---

### Demo on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Robbendebiene/pen/NWqzeEM)

**Note:** This approach can easily be extended to work for vertical positioning. Visit example [here](https://codepen.io/Robbendebiene/pen/vYOagaw).

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me on Chromium. The % for translate is in reference to the size of the bounding box of the element it is applied to so it perfectly gets the element to the lower right edge while not having to switch which property is used to specify it's location.

```
topleft {
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
}
bottomright {
  top: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-100%,-100%);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In more modern browsers (including IE 10+) you can now use [`calc()`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc):

```
.moveto {
  top: 0px;
  left: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```