# Solution to jQuery animation only in CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danradic/VqzvR/12/) animation in jQuery. 
How can this be made only with CSS considering different heights of the images?

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<img class="image" src="http://www.hotel-aramis.com/slider/home/notre-dame-de-paris.jpg"/>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.container {
  position:relative;
  width:1100px;
  height:480px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:#000;
}
.image {
  position:absolute;
  max-width:100%;
  min-width:100%;
```

}

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  move();
});

function move() {
    $img = $(".image");
    diff = $img.height()-$img.parent().height(); 
    speed = diff * 50;
    $img.animate({
    bottom: -diff
    }, speed, 'linear', function(){
    $(this).animate({bottom:0}, speed, 'linear', move);   
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow be sure to accept the best answer given and enjoy your stay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this answer: [CSS transition between left -> right and top -> bottom positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247255/css-transition-between-left-right-and-top-bottom-positions)

which combined with your fiddle, gives you: http://jsfiddle.net/3n1gm4/dvqfs/

```
@-webkit-keyframes pan {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0%,0%);
    }
    100% {
        top: 100%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(0%,-100%);
    }
}

.container {
    position:relative;
    width:1100px;
    height:480px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#000;
}
.image {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    max-width:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    -webkit-animation: pan 3s alternate infinite linear;
}
```