# remove css property on animate()

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div:

```
#content_wrapper { 
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    height: 50px; 
    width: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

I would like to `.animate()` a div from `left: 0px` to `right: 0px` so my attempt was:

```
$('#content_wrapper').animate({'right': 0, 'left':''}, 2000, "easeOutBounce");
```

furthermore I tried

```
$('#content_wrapper').animate({'right': 0, 'left': 'auto'}, 2000, "easeOutBounce");
```

guess what, didnt work.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: generally not good idea to apply left and right position to an element especially for an animation

Comment: @charlietfl why would you say that? So long as the element is `position: absolute` I don't see the issue

Comment: @charlietfl then pls give me an advice how you would animate an element from left to right for every size of the window without offset calculating?

Comment: There is no direct path from `left: 0` to `right: 0` that jQuery can animate along. You need to animate from `left: 0` to `left: 100%` or `left: someValue` so that jQuery can interpolate the interim positions

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  consider fluid container approx 1000px... want child 200px wide....how do you set both left and right in absolute values? Or even percent. One or other has to be changed to `inherit`

Comment: @charlietfl in that case you would set either `left` or `right` and `width`. You'd only set both `left` and `right` if you want the element to stretch with the viewport on resize, keeping the gutter either side to the same size.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  exactly ....set one or other. Op obviously has element with width he wants to move from one side of parent to another

Comment: @supersize  my suggestion would be get parent width....animate `left` based on parent width minus your element width.

Comment: possible duplicate of [css transition between left -> right and top -> bottom positions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247255/css-transition-between-left-right-and-top-bottom-positions)

Answer (score 0):

You could use absolute values as suggested in the comments. For example like this if your div is absolutely positioned in its direct parent:

```
var w = $('#content_wrapper')
w.animate({"left": (w.parent().width()-w.width())+"px"}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/Dd6bx/)

```
<div id="content_wrapper"></div>

#content_wrapper { 
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px; 
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
}

$(function() {
  $('#content_wrapper').animate({ left: $(window).innerWidth() - 50 + 'px' }, 2000, 'easeOutBounce');
});
```