# Moving one div over other using left property

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs like this.The red one and the black one
[image]
 I want to move the inner div over the outer in such a way that at the end of moving, the right most side of inner div should come to the right most edge of outer div.
[image]
for that I added a 'left' style property to inner div and started reducing it from 0.
But the problem is I am not getting any relation between the left and width of both the divs, to know when to stop moving.The width of inner div vary in time and not constant value.At what 'px' I should stop this.

This is my markup

```
<div id="divMenuContainer" style="height:18px;min-width:210px;overflow:hidden;">
            <div id="divMenuContainerInner" style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;">
                <ul id="ulMenuItems">                
                    <li ><a href="#" id="lnkInfo"  onclick="ChangeTab(this)">Info</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="#" id="lnkUsers" onclick="ChangePopupTab(this)">Users</a></li>
                </ul>  
            </div>          
        </div>
```

divMenuContainer is the outer div and divMenuContainerInner is the inner div which i needed to move.Also the `<li/>`can be any number so In the script Im calculating the complete widths of all  and assigning that as the width of inner div. Means the width of inner div varies.

```
var len =0;
$("#ulMenuItems").children("li").each(function (index, element) {
     len = len + parseInt($(element).css("width"), 10);
});
console.log(len);
$("#divMenuContainerInner").css({ "width": len });
```

Please go through this jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/80x5ujyw/1/

---

I found the answer with the help of answers provided here.I have made a jsfiddle on that

### http://jsfiddle.net/q4u37yqe/1/

Modified the above fiddle that now two buttons provided to manually move the inner div
http://jsfiddle.net/sqofk4pe/1/

Comment: We might help you if you provide code, maybe jsfiddle?

Comment: have you tried to switch from `left: 0; right: auto` to `left: auto; right: 0` ?

Comment: @Flopet I havent written a script to do this. Instead trying to figure out the issue using firebug in mozilla firefox.

Comment: I think a mixture of the top 2 answers in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247255/css-transition-between-left-right-and-top-bottom-positions) may be what you are after, but without the top animation

Answer (score 3):

From my understanding, you can use the css `right:0` property to achieve this.

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate moving the inner div to the right most edge of the outer div with JS animation: http://jsfiddle.net/80x5ujyw/

Pasting code here for reference.

JS:

```
$(function(){
    var inner = $('.inner');
    var outer = $('.outer');

    var rightSpacing = parseInt(inner.css('right'))

    interval = setInterval(function(){
        if(rightSpacing < 0){
            clearInterval(interval);
            return;
        }

        inner.css('right', rightSpacing+'px');
        rightSpacing = rightSpacing - 10;
    }, 100);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer, .inner{
    height:100px;
}
.outer{
    position: relative;
    width:200px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background:blue;
}
.inner{
    position: absolute;
    right:50%;
    top:0;
    width:100px;
    background:red;
}
```

Using this approach the width and height of both the inner and outer divs may change at any time without affecting the behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot @WordPress Developer
I modified your fiddle and met my need
http://jsfiddle.net/q4u37yqe/1/

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if you think it is the most suitable one for your question.

Answer (score 1):

You should give both the child as well as the parent div a css position (either relative or absolute).
And then you could give the child (inner) div "right: 0"

```
outer{
    position: relative;
}

inner{
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
}
```

I think you mean something like this, if not you should add some code to your question.