# CSS transition (height property) - can't get it to roll from bottom

Tags: css, transition

I use height property to animate my DIV, it appears on hover of another element - it "rolls" from top. Is there a way to rotate the animation, so I would get it to appear from bottom to top?

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="show">SHOW IT</a>

<div id="appear">
    <img src="http://data.atria.sk/matmenu/celevyk.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#appear {
    width: 308px;
    height: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.show:hover + #appear, #appear:hover {
    height: 331px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8paj437a/)

Comment: Seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247255/css-transition-between-left-right-and-top-bottom-positions.

Just change the .animate.move in that fiddle to be 

  animate.move {
     bottom: 100%;
     margin-top: -100px; /*.animate width*/
   }

Not exactly what your looking for but might send you in the right direction

Comment: Not without changing the document flow by using absolute positioning.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way to do this without using absolute positioning or altering your markup is to transition a `margin-top` at the same time as the height. So your CSS might look like:

```css
html, body { background-color: #dedede; }

#appear {
    width: 308px;
    height: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
    margin-top:331px;
}
.show:hover + #appear, #appear:hover {
    margin-top:0;
    height:331px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="show">SHOW IT</a>

<div id="appear">
    <img src="http://data.atria.sk/matmenu/celevyk.jpg" />
</div>
```

Here's also a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8paj437a/4/) to demonstrate. (If I've misunderstood your intentions, please tell me.)

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 6):

checkout the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8paj437a/2/

I set `position:absolute` to the #appear div. and `bottom:0;` so it will take height from bottom.

And to keep it intact from top. I placed it within a container and give position relative to the container.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="show">SHOW IT</a>

<div class="container">
    <div id="appear">
        <img src="http://data.atria.sk/matmenu/celevyk.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 308px;
    height:331px;
    position:relative;
}
#appear {
    width: 308px;
    height: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
}
.show:hover + .container #appear, .container #appear:hover {
    height: 331px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

By default, height transition works from top to bottom. But you can make it work from `bottom to top` with a very simple trick. All you need is to rotate the div to `180 degrees`. This will rotate the transition direction as well. Try this css on your div.

```
transform: rotate(180deg);
```