# How can I change the direction of the expand/collapse effect in a div text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to get the text opened with the animation from the bottom and not from the top as I did:

```js
function showHide(shID) {
    if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
        if (document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display != 'none') {
            document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById(shID+'-hide').style.display = 'inline';
            document.getElementById(shID).style.height = '100px';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'inline';
            document.getElementById(shID+'-hide').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById(shID).style.height = '0px';
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#example {
    background: red;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 2s;
    -moz-transition: height 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: height 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: height 2s; /* Opera */
}

a.showLink, a.hideLink {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: transparent url('down.gif') no-repeat left; 
}

a.hideLink {
    background: transparent url('up.gif') no-repeat left; 
}
```

```html
Here is some text.
<div class="readmore">
    <a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">Read more</a>
    <div id="example" class="more">
        <div class="text">
            Here is some more text: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            Vestibulum vitae urna nulla. 
            Vivamus a purus mi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In ac tempor quam. 
            Vestibulum eleifend vehicula ligula, et cursus nisl gravida sit amet.
            Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
        </div>
        <p>
            <a href="#" id="example-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">Hide</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bq6eK/13/)

Comment: What do you mean by "from the bottom"? Do you want to see the last part of the content first?

Comment: yes sorry! I'd like to see basically the opposite effect, so that when i expand the text, it opens from the bottom (the last part of the content) towards the top

Comment: no idea how to do it :(

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508316/css-transition-height-property-cant-get-it-to-roll-from-bottom#answer-30508671) does kind of do what you want but with a different animation.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting your request correctly, adding position: absolute, bottom: 0 to the .text CSS, and position: relative to its container, should do what you want.

You'll have to play around with the position of "Hide" afterwards for it to look neat.

```js
function showHide(shID) {
    if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
        if (document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display != 'none') {
            document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById(shID+'-hide').style.display = 'inline';
            document.getElementById(shID).style.height = '100px';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'inline';
            document.getElementById(shID+'-hide').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById(shID).style.height = '0px';
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#example {
    background: red;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 2s;
    -moz-transition: height 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: height 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: height 2s; /* Opera */
    position: relative;
}

a.showLink, a.hideLink {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: transparent url('down.gif') no-repeat left; 
}

a.hideLink {
    background: transparent url('up.gif') no-repeat left; 
}

.text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
Here is some text.
<div class="readmore">
    <a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">Read more</a>
    <div id="example" class="more">
        <div class="text">
            Here is some more text: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            Vestibulum vitae urna nulla. 
            Vivamus a purus mi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In ac tempor quam. 
            Vestibulum eleifend vehicula ligula, et cursus nisl gravida sit amet.
            Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
        </div>
        <p>
            <a href="#" id="example-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">Hide</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Another interpretation is that you want the whole box to open from the bottom. In that case, you need the box to be positioned at the bottom of something for it to be visible. In this case, it's `#example` that has `position:absolute; bottom:0`

```js
function showHide(shID) {
    if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
        if (document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display != 'none') {
            document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById(shID+'-hide').style.display = 'inline';
            document.getElementById(shID).style.height = '135px';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'inline';
            document.getElementById(shID+'-hide').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById(shID).style.height = '0px';
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#example {
    background: red;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 2s;
    -moz-transition: height 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: height 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: height 2s; /* Opera */
    position: absolute; bottom: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
}

a.showLink, a.hideLink {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: transparent url('down.gif') no-repeat left; 
    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;
}

a.hideLink {
    background: transparent url('up.gif') no-repeat left; 
}
```

```html
Here is some text.
<div class="readmore">
    <a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">Read more</a>
    <div id="example" class="more">
        <div class="text">
            Here is some more text: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            Vestibulum vitae urna nulla. 
            Vivamus a purus mi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In ac tempor quam. 
            Vestibulum eleifend vehicula ligula, et cursus nisl gravida sit amet.
            Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
        </div>
        <p>
            <a href="#" id="example-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">Hide</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this still opens from the top to the bottom, OP asked for it to start at the bottom to the top