# transition with right using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a box slide from left to right using **only** transition
like this:

```css
#box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  position:absolute;
  transition: all 2s ease-out;
  right:auto;

}

.active{
  background-color: green !important;
  right:0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" onclick="this.classList.add('active')"></div>
```

but for some reason the box doesn't slide to the right

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10250833/15573857) solution works but there is no explanation to it
can someone please explain why the background color transitions but not the right position?

Comment: Transitions are not possible on „auto“ values. You need e.g. something like 0 to 100% to make it work. 
Transitions from x to auto aren’t possible in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `right: auto;` does not work.

```css
#box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  position:absolute;
  transition: all 2s ease-out;
  right:100%;
  transform: translate(100%,0);

}

.active{
  background-color: green !important;
  right:0 !important;
  transform: translate(0,0) !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" onclick="this.classList.add('active')"></div>
```

Comment: what if we don't know the width? for example I load an image of unknown dimensions into it

Comment: @cakelover in that case, I assume you use Javascript to load the image and you can recalculate the position of right.

Comment: nvm I figured it out, pls check your edits

Answer (score 0):

Try using `animation` instead and add keyframes as in snippet below.

```css
#box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  position:absolute;
  animation: slide 2s forwards ease-out;
  right:auto;

}

  @keyframes slide {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(50%);
    }
}
```

```html
 <div id="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify the 'right' property for the box in px or in %, instead of 'auto'. but using % in position:absolute you have to  set the parent element as position: relative.

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
#box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  position:absolute;
  transition: all 2s ease-out;
  right:calc(100% - 150px);   /* right is positioned to left by reducing the actual box width */

}

.active{
  background-color: green !important;
  right:0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" onclick="this.classList.add('active')"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify the 'right' property for the box in px or in %, instead of 'auto'.

```css
#box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  position:absolute;
  transition: all 2s ease-out;
  right:calc(100% - 150px);   /* right is positioned to left by reducing the actual box width */

}

.active{
  background-color: green !important;
  right:0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" onclick="this.classList.add('active')"></div>
```

Comment: well in this case the answer is correct but what if I didn't know the width of the box for example I had to load an image in it, then what?