# change position on click-javascript animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I create a button to change a div's position on first click with 2sec transition and bring it back on the second click.

I did this but it doesn't bring it back.

```js
var d = document.getElementById("button");
d.addEventListener('click', function() {
  d.className = d.className + " move";
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

Better call is `d.classList.toggle("transitionClassName")`

I copied the transitions from [CSS transition between left -> right and top -> bottom positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247255/css-transition-between-left-right-and-top-bottom-positions)

```js
var d = document.getElementById("button");
d.addEventListener('click', function() {
  d.classList.toggle("move");
  d.classList.toggle("right");
});
```

```css
.animate {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #c00;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  font: 13px/100px sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}


/* ↓ just to position things  */

.animate.left {
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
}

.animate.right {
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
}

.animate.top {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
}

.animate.bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
}

.animate.left.move {
  left: 100%;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}

.animate.right.move {
  right: 100%;
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
}

.animate.top.move {
  top: 100%;
  transform: translate(0, -100%);
}

.animate.bottom.move {
  bottom: 100%;
  transform: translate(0, 100%);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="button" class="animate">Move</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const d = document.getElementById("button");

d.style.transition = "0.8s";

d.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.target.classList.toggle("move");
});
```

```css
.move {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Click Me!</button>
```