# Transition issue in a JavaScript animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an animation problem that I can't seem to solve. Here is the purpose of the animation:

1. The card is initially placed in the bottom-right corner of its wrapper, with opacity set to 0.
2. Then, the card moves to the bottom-left corner of its wrapper, and the opacity transitions to 1 over a duration of one second.
3. Next, the card moves upwards within the wrapper by a number of pixels equal to its size, with a one-second transition.
4. Step 3 is repeated, one movement at a time, until the card exceeds the height of the wrapper. During its last movement, the card returns to an opacity of 0.

So far this is the code:

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
const card = document.querySelector('.card');
card.style.bottom = '0';
card.style.right = '0';
card.style.opacity = '0';
requestAnimationFrame(() => {

  card.style.transition = '1s';
  card.style.bottom = '0';
  card.style.right = 'auto';
  card.style.left = '0';
  card.style.opacity = '1';
  const cardHeight = card.offsetHeight;
  const wrapperHeight = wrapper.offsetHeight;

  function moveCard() {
    if (parseInt(card.style.bottom) < wrapperHeight) {
      card.style.transition = '1s';
      card.style.bottom = parseInt(card.style.bottom) + cardHeight + 'px';
      card.style.opacity = '1';
      setTimeout(moveCard, 1000);
    } else if (parseInt(card.style.bottom) >= wrapperHeight && card.style.opacity !== '0') {
      // Dernier mouvement : Repasser à une opacité de 0
      card.style.transition = '1s';
      card.style.opacity = '0';
      setTimeout(moveCard, 1000);
    }
  }
  setTimeout(moveCard, 1000);
});
```

```css
.wrapper{
  display:flex;
  height : 200px;
  width : 300px;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
}
.card{
  position: absolute;
  width:50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class= "wrapper">
  <div class="card">
  
</div>
</div>
```

Why doesn't the transition on the first translate work?

Comment: There is no way for CSS to transition `right` from 0 to "auto". What number comes just before "auto"? Set it to `100%` or something countable, then it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find this helpful: [CSS transition between left -> right and top -> bottom positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247255/css-transition-between-left-right-and-top-bottom-positions). The issue is that you're trying to translate with left and right, and the browser sees those as distinct. Try leaving `left` out and translating with the right only, in this case:

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
const card = document.querySelector('.card');
card.style.bottom = '0';
card.style.right = '0';
card.style.opacity = '0';

requestAnimationFrame(() => {

  card.style.transition = '1s';
  card.style.bottom = '0';
  card.style.right = '250px';
  card.style.opacity = '1';
  const cardHeight = card.offsetHeight;
  const wrapperHeight = wrapper.offsetHeight;

  function moveCard() {
    if (parseInt(card.style.bottom) < wrapperHeight) {
      card.style.transition = '1s';
      card.style.bottom = parseInt(card.style.bottom) + cardHeight + 'px';
      card.style.opacity = '1';
      setTimeout(moveCard, 1000);
    } else if (parseInt(card.style.bottom) >= wrapperHeight && card.style.opacity !== '0') {
      // Dernier mouvement : Repasser à une opacité de 0
      card.style.transition = '1s';
      card.style.opacity = '0';
      setTimeout(moveCard, 1000);
    }
  }
  setTimeout(moveCard, 1000);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card">

  </div>
</div>
```